# Is it possible to have "Setup-geterator-functions" for nosetests?

Tags: python, nose

I have an application X in it's various versions, say - a,b and c.

I am using nose (I don't have a choice, nose is the "choosen-one" at my workplace) to test the features of X in a black-box kind of way.

Now, I wrote a test - "test_feature1_of_X". My intention is to be able to run this test for all the versions of X, namely a,b and c.

My first thought was to have generator tests, but for each version there is a setup that needs to be done, might be different for each version, so I was thinking if it is possible to have a package level setup-function that would run 3 times and after each run, set up the one version of X at a time and then, all the tests are run in that package.

Is this even possible with nose? If yes, how?

Current Progress:

So after spending a day with the problem, I am trying out the following, not sure if this will work, so maybe... correct me.

```
class randomTest(someBaseTest):

    def setup_for_V_a(self):
        # do setup

    def teardown_for_V_a(self):
        # do teardown

    @with_setup(setup_for_V_a, teardown_for_V_a)
    def test_generator_for_V_a(self):
        yield test_all, self

    def setup_for_V_b(self):
        # do setup

    def teardown_for_V_b(self):
        # do teardown

    @with_setup(setup_for_V_b, teardown_for_V_b)
    def test_generator_for_V_b(self):
        yield test_all, self

    def test_all(self):
        yield first_featuretest, self
        yield second_featuretest, self

    def first_featuretest(self):
        # test feature unu

    def second_test(self):
        # test feature du
```

Why is this setup not a good idea?

Forgive me for any python sin, new(very) to the language.

Comment: `nose` has been dead for a long time, you really should be migrating to `pytest` or something.

Comment: While I appreciate the suggestion, but choice is not a privilage I have in the current predicament.